# Creating Mobile Applications using Visual Studio 2010 Professional Academic Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can you create mobile applications with Visual Studio 2010 Professional **Academic Edition**?

Can you create mobile websites with Visual Studio 2010 Professional **Academic Edition**?

Answer (score 2):

You can create mobile websites with Notepad, if that's what you wanted to use.

Creating a Mobile Website is a matter of designing the website to look good and work on the phone. It has nothing to do with Visual Studio or any other [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

The most popular trend today (and something I'm currently studying) is [Responsive Web Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx). Which is a web design method where a site is designed to work at any resolution and will scale to that resolution without any changes to code. It's kind of brain rewire to get the hang of if you've been designing websites for even a short period of time, but it's extremely fascinating and useful. Responsive Web Design makes use of fluid grids and media. If you want, you could also have an  adaptive layout using fixed widths (like [colly.com](http://colly.com)) without the fluid stuff. Responsive web design is generally considered a better approach as it does not assume any particular device dimensions.

Mobile applications however, are not written in any language that Visual Studio Supports. The most popular are:

- Android - Written in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)
- iOS (Apple) - Written in [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)

Visual Studio **will** work for creating mobile applications designed for Windows Mobile Devices, running any Windows Mobile OS that's ever been released.

---

Also, as a side note:

Microsoft has discontinued Academic Edition and offers VS 2008 through VS 2012 Beta for free to students with a college email  address through [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/), along side some other cool free stuff.

There is also [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express), which is free and supports MVC3.